# Change source data for multiple Excel pivot tables but not using cache

Tags: excel, vba

I have to answer hundreds of questions from the same source data, which is an 85mb file (about 300k rows). I've created pivot tables to answer the questions but in a separate file from the source data to make it all manageable.

My problem is that after I've set up a bunch of pivot tables, I notice I need to create another column in the source data (to group data for a filter), which affects the range I originally used in the pivot tables. This happens even if I use a named range for the source data.

Because I have so many pivot tables and the source data is so huge, I do not want to use the pivot table cache. All methods I've seen on how to change the source data range relies on the cache.  Is there a way to do this without the cache or to use the cache then turn it off?

I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Any success or update?

Answer (score 1):

A PivotTable has to be built on top of a PivotCache. You can't separate the two and still have a PivotTable.

Could you just add your filter field to the end of your data set so the existing PivotCache doesn't automatically pick it up, then create a new pivot table using the new larger range? That would create two PivotCaches, one original one without the filter, and a new one with the filter. The downside to this method is that PivotCaches take up disk space and it will bloat the size of your sheet. A cache is roughly the same size of the data it's based on, so this would probably double the size of your worksheet.

Comment: I get that a pivot table can't be built w/o the cache, however there's always the option to not save the source data and to disable drilling down. You just then have to refresh the pivots whenever you open the file. So there is some way to keep/refresh a pivot w/o the cache.  I don't want to create pivots w/o the cache, I want to update the range w/o the cache (like forcing it to preserve the named range, which it seems to do sometimes; I must not have done it right the first time).